# Split a String after the logical operator present in string

Tags: python-3.x

`ABC="1,485.00 or £54/month"`

Suppose I have this ABC string. And I want to get the value before the "or".

I have tried this so far using the split method.

`ABC=ABC.partition['or'][1]`, and
`ABC=ABC.partition['£'][1][:-3]`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-6bbd79452e2e> in <module>
      1 ABC="1,485.00 or £54/month"
----> 2 ABC=ABC.partition['or'][1]
      3 ABC

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the argument `'or'` in `()` and not `[]`. Also you wanted to get the substring before the or that would be done with `[0]` since in most of programming arrays start with the index 0.

```
In [1]: ABC="1,485.00 or £54/month"                                                                                                           

In [2]: ABC=ABC.partition('or')                                                                                                               

In [3]: ABC                                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: ('1,485.00 ', 'or', ' £54/month')

In [4]: ABC[0]                                                                                                                                
Out[4]: '1,485.00 '
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. I don't know why it is not working before.